# slick setting active slide

Tags: javascript, php, carousel, slick.js

I have implemented slick (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and everything is fine except the first slide is the first image shown rather than the one clicked on from the list of images, say image 5, image 1 would be displayed. I am using PHP to try and automate the process.

The col-sm-4 while loop displays all the images on the page, then when clicked a modal with the slick will popup and display the images inside the modal. As I said this process works fine, except the position of the image that is clicked. For eg, I click image 6 from the col-sm-4 list of images, but image 1 is displayed.

I would appreciate any assistance from the community. Thanks

**UPdate .. add a data/var and counter menuid to each div, I am just not sure how to access it in the Slick JS initialSlide option shown below: **

```
<div class="row">

            <?php 

            $query_gallery = "SELECT name, image_location, gallery_id FROM cms_gallery order by image_place asc";

            $newmenu = new menu();
            $value = $newmenu->mysqlquery($query_gallery);

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($value))
            { ?>      

                            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                                <a title='<?php echo($row[0]); ?> href='#'> 
                                    <img class='thumbnail img-responsive images' id='<?php echo($row[2]); ?>' title='<?php echo($row[0]); ?>' src='<?php echo($row[1]); ?>' data-menuid="<?php echo($row[2]); ?>">
                                    <p class='images text-center'><?php echo($row[0]); ?></p>
                                    <p id="demo"></p>
                                </a>
                            </div>
            <?php } ?>


                            <div class='modal' id='modal-gallery' role='dialog'>
                              <div class='modal-dialog'>
                                <div class='modal-content'>
                                  <div class='modal-header'>
                                      <button class='close' type='button' data-dismiss='modal'>×</button>
                                      <h3 class='modal-title text-center'></h3>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class='modal-body'>
                                      <div id='modal-carousel' class='text-center'>


                                        <div class='your-content'>
                                        <?php 

                                        $query_gallery = "SELECT name, image_location, gallery_id FROM cms_gallery order by image_place asc";

                                        $newmenu = new menu();
                                        $value = $newmenu->mysqlquery($query_gallery); $counter = 0;

                                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($value))
                                        { ?> 
                                        <div id="menulist" data-menuid="<?php echo $counter++; ?>">
                                                <h1>'<?php echo($row[0]); ?>'</h1>
                                                <img class='modal-thumbnail' id='<?php echo($row[2]); ?>' title='<?php echo($row[0]); ?>' src='<?php echo($row[1]); ?>' data-menuid="<?php echo($row[2]); ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                  <div class='modal-footer'>
                                      <button class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>                          
            </div>
            </div>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
<script>


$('.thumbnail').click(function(){
 $("#modal-gallery").modal("show");//.modal('show')/.modal('hide');
});


var menulist = $("#menulist");
var menuid = menulist.data("menuid");

    $( "#menulist" ).click(function() {
    var myId = $( "#menulist" ).data("menuid");
    $( "#menulist" ).attr("menuid", myId);
    });

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.your-content').slick({
      /* lazyLoad: 'ondemand', */
      /* centerMode: true, */
      dots: true,
      /* infinite: true, */
      speed: 500,
      fade: true,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      cssEase: 'linear',
      /* initialSlide: 1, */
      setPosition: 1,
      /* slickGoTo: 8, */
      initialSlide: menuid
  });
});

</script>
```